# SUMIFS: How to write column names as formula while specifying a range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, excel-match

There are columns B through Z in the table. I want to sum the column that contains "Mar-15" as the heading, provided column A's value is greater than or equal to "Mar-15".

So, if I have the following in Sheet1 -

```
     A       B       C       D       E
1          Mar-15   Apr-15  May-15  Jun-15
2 Feb-15    1       2       3       4
3 Mar-15    100     200     300     400
4 Apr-15    1000    2000    3000    4000
5 May-15    10000   20000   30000   40000
```

And I have the following in columns Y and Z -

```
    Y       Z
1 Month    Value
2 Mar-15    ?
```

I want to be able to write a formula in Z2, that sums the values in the column which has the heading equal to Y2, and where column A is greater than or equal to Y2. So here, the required answer for the formula would be **1110** since Y2 contains **Mar-15**.

To be clearer, if Y2 contains **Apr-15**, then the result in Z2 should be **22000**

Now, I have the formula

```
=MATCH(Y2,$1:$1,0)
```

which gives me 2, which is the column index in the first row, that matches with the value in Y2.

Then, I modify it to get the address of the heading -

```
=ADDRESS(1,MATCH(Y2,$1:$1,0))
```

This gives me **$B$1**. To get the column alone, I am doing `=LEFT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(Y2,$1:$1,0)),2)` which gives me **$B**

Now, I want to do a `SUMIFS` of the column returned by this address function, and specify the condition that column A should be greater than the value in Y2.

```
=SUMIFS(<something>,A:A,">="&Y2)
```

What should **something** be? Depending on the value in Y2, the column which I want summed can be different. So what formula do I insert in place of **something**?

I tried `LEFT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(Y2,$1:$1,0)),2):LEFT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(Y2,$1:$1,0)),2)` since `LEFT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(Y2,$1:$1,0)),2)` gives me **$B** and I presumed this formula would give me **$B:$B**, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A row or column can be 'spliced' out of a rectangular matrix with the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a). A `, 0,` or empty parameter (e.g. `, ,`) is used to note all cells in the opposite parameter. In this case, a **0** will mean all rows in the column that is selected.

[image: sumif_index]

The formula in Z2 can be one either of these,

```
=SUMIF(A:A, ">="&Y2, INDEX(B:E, 0, MATCH(Y2, B$1:E$1, 0)))
=SUMIFS(INDEX(B:E, 0, MATCH(Y2, B$1:E$1, 0)),A:A, ">="&Y2)
```

If you have additional values in Y3, etc. fill down as necessary.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! I was playing around with the INDEX function, but couldn't quite get it right the way you did. Thanks a ton! It works like a charm :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A200>=Y2),INDEX(B2:E200,0,MATCH(Y2,B1:E1,0)))
```

It is using MATCH to find which column to look at with the range B2:E200 (the 0, means all rows in that selected column). The test `A2:A200>=Y2` checks the first column as you specified, the -- changes matches to 1 misses to 0, and `SUMPRODUCT` then multiplies those 1/09 by the selected column values to get the result.

If you want further reading see [here](http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.SUMPRODUCT.html)

Comment: Why the SUMPRODUCT instead of SUMIF?